# SQL Server stored procedure after insert row return string value of column data truncated

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have been trying to return string value after insert however my data is always truncated. It returns only the first character of the string.

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_add_user]
    (@firstName nvarchar(50),
     @lastName nvarchar(50),
     @email nvarchar(100),
     @password nvarchar(100),
     @userID nvarchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @userID = newid()

    INSERT INTO [User] ([UserID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [Password])
    VALUES (@userID, @firstName, @lastName, @email, @password)

    SELECT @userID;
END
```

My C# how I am trying to catch the value

```
access.Parameter["@userID"].Value.ToString();
```

When I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it shows everything correctly, my `@userID` is correct. However when it comes back to my Visual Studio I only get first character

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the size to get the entire string

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
cmd.Parameters["@userID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```